# Import android project from Eclipse to Android Studio issues

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have application that i developed on "Eclipse" the application contains actionBar with background image.
After i imported the project to "Android Studio" i have a lot of issues:

1. The TimePicker and the DatePicker widgets on my app changed to the new pickers and i want exactly what i have before (the old pickers, i think it was holo picker or something like that..).
2. Action bar now with black color(no image background on the actionBar.. i do using my style same like on eclipse)
3. Fragment crashing when i tried to enter them.

In the gradle I'm using:

```
       compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    ....
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 23
...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

but on my eclipse project(Manifest) i used

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />


<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="Theme.custom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/customActionBar</item>
       <item name="android:logo">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_selector</item>
    </style>



<style name="customActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateProgressStyle">@style/myProgress</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_wood_port_actionbar</item>


</style>

<style name="myProgress" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_bar</item>
</style>


    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

     <style name="shadow">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#2b2b2b</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
    </style>
     <style name="shadowHeader">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#2b2b2b</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">5</item>
    </style>
     <style name="shadowRed">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/red</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">8</item>
    </style>
     <style name="shadowWhite">
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">-2</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">13</item>
    </style>



        <style name="Animations" />
         <style name="Animations.SmileWindow">
                <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/push_down_in</item>
                <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/push_right_out</item>
        </style>

        <style name="AnimationsFromDown" />
         <style name="Animations.SmileWindowFromDown">
                <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/push_down_out</item>
                <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/push_right_in</item>
        </style>

             <style name="Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth">
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Android Studio changed my all Theme of my application.
I just want the project will be exactly like on eclipse ? any idea what i missing?

Comment: please give your style.xml file! i thick you use something from Theme.AppCompat right ?

Comment: @hamidrezabstn look above ^

Comment: ok as i expected you use Theme.AppCompat !!! i think changing your support library version from 22  to  23 cause that ! check support library appcompat v7 changelog !
(developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set `targetSdkVersion` to `22`, as you had in Eclipse project.

All support libraries MUST be a same version. Please setup exact version as in Eclipse project.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Copy resource files from Eclipse project, if some of them were changed.

Android Studio import wizard tries to do the best for you, offers upgrade to latest support libraries, SDK version and etc. But if you don't like it, setup and copy original resources & source files from Eclipse project.